# React native use Effect not displaying list while rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am on React native , i am  fetching data from my  prestashop api I need to display the list of cinemas whenever we open the cinemas screens. in this case I use Useeffect
but it doesn't automatically display the list I have to save the code to display the list.

[fetching actions [][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttPCx.png)

Comment: Your pictures is displaying everything but not your useEffect. Also don't put pictures of your code in StackOverflow, text format is the correct way to go.

Comment: thanks for the info. this is the code :

Comment: const fetchCinemaName = async () => {
       
        const urls = await getCineUrls()

        Promise.all(
            urls.map( async (url) => {
                 await getCineName(url);
                })
                )
                setIsDisplay(true);
      

     } 


     
   useEffect( async () => {

     
       await fetchCinemaName()

    
     
   }, [isDisplay])

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.